# make a salad with 4 toppings

Tags: permutations, combinations

you have 4 toppings how many ways can you make the sandwich

Comment: I'd rather have a burger.

Comment: haha                  that was a funny joke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

1 of 2 dressings (x2)

At least one of three lettuces
(seclude one case of not choosing any lettuce from the total, 8-1=7)

And then up to 4 other(taking them as unique) ingredients,
(2^4 = 16)

So I assume, 224 salads.

Comment: hey updated the question, made a mistake. Any help on this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I understand,

Comment: Do you mean I made a mistake?

Comment: i mean i made a mistake with the question

Comment: Hmm, but I didn't notice any changes in your question, (still don't) so I got confused,

Comment: Oh.. 'salads--> dressings' :))

Comment: yeah sorry about that

Comment: there, changed my wordings, too. but the answer would stay the same.